# Finding potential for a vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Find the potential function for the vector field $$\frac{16x}z\hat{\mathbf i}+\frac{18y}z\hat{\mathbf j}+\left(1-\frac{8x^2 +9y^2}{z^2}\right)\hat{\mathbf k}$$ which has no constant terms.

So far I have $$f = \frac8z x^2 +\frac9z y^2 +g(z).$$ The $z$ term kinda messes things up and I'm not really able to get any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Step $1$:
   $$
   f(x,y,z)=\int \frac{16x}{z}\; dx + g(y,z) = \frac{8x^2}{z}+g(y,z)
   $$
2. Step $2$:
   $$
   \frac{\partial{f(x,y,z)}}{\partial{y}}= \frac{\partial{g(y,z)}}{\partial{y}} = \frac{18y}{z}\quad \Rightarrow \quad g(y,z) = \frac{9y^2}{z}+h(z)
   $$
3. Step $3$:
   $$
   \frac{\partial{f(x,y,z)}}{\partial{z}}= -\frac{8x^2}{z^2} -\frac{9y^2}{z^2}  + h'(z) = (1-\frac{8x^2 +9y^2}{z^2}) \quad \Rightarrow \quad h(z) = z+K\quad (K\in \mathbb{R})
   $$
   Therefore
   $$
   f(x,y,z)=\frac{8x^2}{z}+\frac{9y^2}{z}+z+K
   $$
   And if there are no constant terms then obviously $K=0$.